# Sample libraries with cartoon sounds?

Tags: cartoon, sound-effects, library, sample

I'm looking for sample libraries with generic cartoon sounds. Mainly those zips and swishes you'll hear when characters move instantly in or out of the picture.

In general, any experience, tips or resources regarding cartoon sounds would also be highly appreciate.
I tried doing some on my own, but I think I have to face that my $2 slide-whistle and 30 minutes of experimentation doesn't make me an expert on cartoon sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic Sound Ideas 4000 series should help you.
http://www.sound-ideas.com/4000.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want classic, but slightly recognizable cartoon effects: http://www.sound-ideas.com/hb.html

Comment: I found a slew of recognizable 'signature' effects in there from the original War of The Worlds.  Too funny.

Answer (score 2):

Hi, this is another sfx library that is good: http://www.sound-ideas.com/rocky.html

Answer (score 2):

This, too: Warner Brothers. http://www.sound-ideas.com/wb.html

Answer (score 1):

Do yourself a big favor and Google Treg Brown and Jimmy MacDonald. It's worth the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,I'll take a look at all of these! Up vote for all ifi had 15 rep :-).

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a huge favor and start creating your own library. Not that difficult and a lot more satisfactory.

Comment: I might want to do that for the future, it does sound like a lot of fun. Do you have any resources or tips on getting started with cartoon sounds specifically, where should I begin? I do have some foley and field recording experience, but nothing like this.

Comment: Well, I really don't know how you should start. But let me tell you what I did today. I have some boxes full of small coils, tin cans, nuts, screws etc, and I spent a few hours making sounds with them. 

Some of them actually produce pleasant sounds, such as a pen coil being pinched while attached to a resonant tin can. That boing sound will be really useful one day.

You get the idea. You don't need tips or resources, just ears and decent recording gear.

Comment: Also: Get a slide whistle and start playing around with it. I have a client who wants slide whistle somewhere in each of her projects, so I have a few around the studio and have done loads of slide whistle work (as weird as that sounds). That's probably the beginnings of a library right there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of cartoon sound effects found at http://rocksuresoundz.com/store/cartoon/

As mentioned by others here, it can also be fun creating and recording some of your own "unique" sound effects. With a bit of imagination many common items round the home can be maniputed to create interesting effects. Dropping a bunch of pots and pans on the floor to create various crashes and clatters, or pitch shifting and/or time expansion of various springs are a couple of possible examples. Manipulating Balloons can also produce intersting sounds. Speeding up of some sounds and changing their pitches can do interesting things to them